# How to obtain Uppercase string from a sentence in clojure?

Tags: string, clojure, uppercase

I am new to clojure and not well versed with the available functions. So I wanted to know how to retrieve uppercase words from a sentence.
For Example:
Input: IllegalArgumentException contains? not SUPPORTED on type: java.lang.String  clojure.lang.RT.contains
Output: SUPPORTED

Comment: Converted the string to a vector by splitting the spaces & then ran this below function
(loop [x 0]
          (if (< x (count vecter))
            (do
              (if (every? #(Character/isUpperCase %) (get vecter x))
                (println (get vecter x)))
            (recur (inc x)))))

Comment: @OlegTheCat But wanted a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use regular expression like in any other language:

```
(re-find #"\b[A-Z]+\b" s)
;; => "SUPPORTED"
```

If there's more than one expected match, you can use `re-seq`:

```
(re-seq #"\b[A-Z]+\b" "THIS is a TEST")
;; => ("THIS" "TEST")
```

Since you mentioned you're not well-versed with regards to available functions, please check out [ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org).

Answer (score -1):

First we write a function that tests whether a string is upper-case or not.

```
(defn upper-case? [word]
    (= word (clojure.string/upper-case word)))
```

Then we split any string into words and filter out all words that are not upper-case. In your example there was at least one instance of two consecutive spaces, so those had to be filtered out as well.

```
(defn upper-case-words [sentence]
    (filterv #(and (upper-case? %) (not= "" %)) (clojure.string/split sentence #" ")))

(upper-case-words "Input: IllegalArgumentException contains? not SUPPORTED on type: java.lang.String  clojure.lang.RT.contains")
["SUPPORTED"]
```

Comment: this is bad because upper-case of \* is itself

Comment: The expand on the previous comment from @fasttooth: the danger with this implementation is that it will `true` if given input with no alphabetic characters. It will return `true` if given something like `"1, 2, 3"` or `"!@#$%^"` which may not ideal in some cases.